# Need to call a function inside another function in JSL

Tags: javascript, jenkins, groovy, jenkins-groovy

I'm using below groovy code to delete single uploads using upload id but while trying for multiple deletion using the upload id its getting error.

```
/* The below function will delete upload files */

def delete_upload(server_url,each_upload_id,authentication){

    def delete_upload_url  = server_url + "/api/v1/uploads/" + upload_id

  
    def response =  httpRequest consoleLogResponseBody: true,
                    contentType: 'APPLICATION_JSON',
                    customHeaders: [[maskValue: false, name: 'id ', value: each_upload_id],
                    [maskValue: false, name: 'Authorization', value: authentication]],
                    httpMode: 'DELETE', ignoreSslErrors: true, responseHandle: 'NONE', url: delete_upload_url,
                    validResponseCodes: '100:599'
  
    def result = readJSON text: """${response.content}"""
    
    if(response.status == 202){
       println ("Status code")
    } else{ 
       throw new Exception("Incorrect upload id! Please give the correct upload id.")
    }

    return result['message'].toString()
}

/* The below function will delete multiple uploads that exist in the server using upload id */

def delete_multiupload(server_url, upload_id, group_name, authentication){

   String filepath = readfile "/data/Make/upload id.txt"
   println (filepath)

   def list = filepath.split(','). collect {it}
   printIn(list)

   list.each {
   upload_id ->
   printin "Calling the delete API for the upload id: $upload_id"

   def delete_response = delete_upload (server_ur1,upload_id, group_name, authentication)
   
   }
}
```

---

I'm getting below error,

```
 The current scope already contains a variable of the name upload_id
 @ line 34, column 14.
      list.each {
                ^

1 error
```

---

The delete_upload function is working fine.I'm trying to add another function delete_multiupload for multiple uploads deletion.

**Requirement**: I need to use/call delete_upload function inside delete_multiupload so it can delete multiple uploads.

Any suggestions ?

Comment: seeing as this is javascript, keep the tags to javascript as well

Comment: it's exactly as the error tells you, you are trying to create a new variable named upload_id, but you already have a variable in that function with that name. Check the parameters

Comment: I need to use the delete_upload function inside delete_multiupload but if i change the variable name of upload_id to input_upload_id it gives me the error: groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: input_upload_id for class: groovy.lang.Binding